# My function that detects keydown and value does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input bar, where text can be typed in.

I am trying to get the console.log to run as soon as the user clicks on backspace and because of that leaves the input with no value.

Right now the console.log only runs if the backspace is clicked while there isn't any value in the input.

**GOAL** - The console should ONLY run if clicking on backspace CAUSES the input to be empty.

```js
$("#friendsNames").keydown(function(event){
          if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            if ($("#friendsNames").val() == "") {
              console.log("Works!");
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" name="namesOfFriend" id="friendsNames" value=""  />
```

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to achieve.    Do you actually want an alert for _any_ action that causes the box to become empty?

Comment: A button should be removed when a user erases the last input.. However, instead of going into detail, I have just used console as an example

Comment: OK, but there _are_ other ways of erasing input, such as pasting over blank text.

Comment: You can check through `keyup` event that make whatever you want when you erase last input from input box. @JonasSH

Comment: So how would you write that code?

Comment: I already write that code in my answer @JonasSH

Comment: As @Alnitak points out, there are other ways, such as using the *delete* key (with cursor at the start of the text) or cut (ctrl-x or menu with all text highlighted) or paste empty (ctrl-v or menu with all text highlighted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not tracking key strokes at all, but monitoring the *content* of the box using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event which fires when that content changes:

```js
$("#friendsNames").on('input', function(event) {
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
        console.log("Works!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="namesOfFriend" id="friendsNames" value=""  />
```

This ensures that *any* interaction that results in the input becoming empty will trigger your code.

Comment: That is actually a better way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: A perfect example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/346811)

Comment: @freedomn-m indeed, yes!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want console.log to execute only where this is any value in the input box, else it shouldn't execute, right? Based on this, below is the code:

```js
$("#friendsNames").on('input', function(){
          var inputValue = $(this).val();
          if(inputValue.length == 0)
              console.log("Works!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="namesOfFriend" id="friendsNames" value=""  />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The console.log should only run if clicking on backspace causes the input to be empty

Comment: Updated after understanding that it should fire only when input is empty.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Basically your function should run the console 1 step earlier. Now it runs when clicking on backspace WHILE there is nothing in input. It should run when clicking on backspace CAUSES input to be empty.

Comment: Code has been updated. It would have been great, had you let us know the GOAL before. There are multiple ways to achieve.

Comment: I actually did. I wrote "I am trying to get the console.log to run as soon as the user clicks on backspace and because of that leaves the input with no value.".. But thanks @Milan Chheda.. You code works perfectly!

Comment: @JonasSH no, it doesn't.   Try putting in some text, selecting all (ctrl-a) and cut (ctrl-x).  You've got an empty box, but your console line didn't appear.

Comment: Valid @Alnitak. Have updated the code. Keydown, Keyup, Keypress won't really work in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make event on `keyup` coz if input field empty and you're going to enter first character in it `console.log()` calls. So try this code or go through mention link [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/166/)

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$("#friendsNames").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val() == "") {
    console.log("Works!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. The function should ONLY run if clicking on backspace causes the input to be empty

Comment: Doesn't work the way it should. Now I have to click backspace an extra time even though there is nothing in inout

Comment: What you're trying to achieve when backspace pressed in input box? @JonasSH

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#friendsNames").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 8 || $(this).val() != "") {
    alert("Works!");
  }
});
```